# How to install Ubuntu with USB

Tags: system-installation, dell, live-usb

It has been hard for me, following  directions I can find online on the Ubuntu sites and others, how to simply get 14.04 LTS loaded on to a Windows laptop.

I want to get remove  Windows 7 on the laptop and  replace with 14.04. I'm looking for step by step directions.

I found  a download button, nothing more than that. What do you do with the download once you get on your desktop.

Then I went to another directions page, and it says download from a DVD. How do I get it on the DVD? How do I use it from a memory stick, it is all I have.

Comment: Yes, I have been using Ubuntu 12for quite a while. The only reason I want to upgrade is when I boot up, I started getting a 'grub restore'....want to avoid grup repair.  when I go to the Ubuntu site and hit 'download' for the 14 OS, i get a desktop icon on my functiong hp laptop with MS OS. Then what in the world am I supposed to do then? PUt the icon on a memory stick and then stick memory stick in drive of old computer with 'grub restore' issue? There are so many missing parts to this puzzle. I don't see how I'll ever get 14 on my old computer...or another laptop.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First step calm down. You will not get what you want by shouting out your problem (YOUR USING ALL CAPS), in fact you will probably get ignored, more then likely you don't have your BIOS configured properly to boot a USB drive to install Ubuntu, set that up first then try loading it. Just a suggestion maybe try testing out Ubuntu first before installing, unless you have tested it before and you know what your expecting. Also make sure you backup all your music files, video files and documents that you can't afford to lose as Linux uses a different file system (ex4) then Windows (NTFS) so in the process of installing it will format your hard drive and you will not be able to restore it.